# Submit form iframe Mozilla

Tags: json, form, iframe

Есть форма вида

```
<form method="post" name="fs" target="uploadFrame"></form>
```

по кнопке инициализируется ф-ция делающая `document.forms['fs'].submit();`
в результате скрипт обработчик возвращает код вида

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.jsonCallBack({".$json_str."});
</script>
```

Код ф-ции `jsonCallBack` обрабатывает полученные JSON-данные, меняет скрытые переменные формы и заново делает

```
console.log('submit form'); 
document.forms['fs'].submit();
```

Всё это должно продолжаться пока не пройдёт весь нужный цикл.

Всё прекрасно работает в Chrome но перестало работать в Mozilla в последнее время, если же заменить `console.log` на `alert`, то в Mozilla также происходит `submit`.

Вероятно и скорей всего именно так,  что повторного `submit` формы не происходит из за того что при проверке

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('uploadFrame');
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
console.log('iframe_status: '+iframeDoc.readyState);
```

Статус = LOADING хотя раз ф-ция `window.parent.jsonCallBack` стала выполняться, то по логике контент уже должен быть загружен.

вопрос снимается, ответ сервера изменён на

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
     { 
       window.parent.jsonCallBack({".$json_str."});
     };
</script>
```

Comment: простите, зачем эти сложности с фрэймом? `$.ajax({..., success: function(data) { ... }});`

Comment: покажите полный, но минимальный пример где замена console.log на alert делает код рабочим.  Как вы определяете что работает не работает (на сервере логи что говорят?) [mcve]

Comment: не добавляйте решение (ответ) в ваш вопрос. Опубликуйте ответ как ответ -- [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). См. «Отправить ответ» внизу.

Answer (score 0):

ответ сервера изменён на

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
 { 
   window.parent.jsonCallBack({".$json_str."});
 };
```